# SSD Server with trim enabled

Tags: linux, windows, unix, ssd

I have a Windows Server (but I think this problem may apply to any UNIX server too) running using SSD. I have Kingston UV300 SSD and they allow TRIM. I also checked and my Windows is running with TRIM enabled.

My question is this: after my server deletes files the TRIM feature of Windows and SSD should make any deleted files to be automatically "zeroed" at the SSD. But that is not the case: when I delete several files (also removed from recycle bin) and I run RECUVA I can recover most of the deleted files!

Why TRIM is not making it's job correctly and preventing data from being recovered?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what TRIM is.  It's "job" is not to prevent deleted data from being recovered.  It's job is to let the firmware in the SSD know that it no longer *needs* to preserve data ( because it has been deleted ), and armed with that knowledge, the firmware may be able to do a better job of managing the data that it *does* need to preserve.  This information is meerly a hint that may improve performance; the drive is entirely free to completely ignore the TRIM command.

Comment: The "job" DOES NOT MATTER AT ALL. If TRIM was working, the job could be ANYTHING. It could be secure privacy, improve performance... IT DOES NOT MATTER. TRIM IS NOT WORKING, Your answer is nothing more than shit.

Comment: @Samul, would you also claim that a hammer is not working because it won't screw in a screw?  You're using the wrong tool for the job dingus.

Comment: sometimes people on SO are not good at understanding, and you look like a person like that. WHEN DID I SAY I WANT TO GET PRIVACY USING TRIM??? When? When did I say that I will rely on TRIM to secure my deleted data???? I am not using TRIM as a tool for any job at all. I never said that. I want to know why TRIM is not zeroing data in the SSD. You should better read the question.

Comment: @Samul, stop throwing a childish tantrum and pay attention and try to get it this time: it isn't zeroing your data because it is not *supposed* to zero your data.

Comment: you have no idea what you are saying... stupid things... you have no idea what is trim

Comment: @Samul, yes, I who have actually read the ATA standard am stupid because because the all knowing Samul says so; I bow before your superior intellect.